# wso2 DSS Value type miss match, Expected value type - 'dateTime', but found - 'STRING'

Tags: json, apache, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-data-services-server

I want to save this object in to database with wso2 dss. but it is showing there is an error in the date format.

```
Value type miss match, Expected value type - 'dateTime', but found - 'STRING'
```

example post messgae is this

```
{
"insert_subscribe_merchant_operation":
{
        "customerrefid": 1,
        "merchantrefid": "1",
        "datetime": "2012-03-14T00:00:00+05:30",
        "registereddevice":"1234567890",
        "latlongregistered": "xczv",
        "totalpoints":1000,
        "redeemablepoints":800,
        "expirydate": "2012-03-14T00:00:00+05:30",
        "qrcode": "xvc",
        "currentoffercount":10,
        "schemerefid":1
      }
}
```

but when i tried with the xml type it is working fine

```
<insert_subscribe_merchant_operation>
         <customerrefid>1</customerrefid>
         <merchantrefid>"1"</merchantrefid>
         <datetime>2012-03-14T00:00:00+05:30</datetime>
         <registereddevice>"1234567890"</registereddevice>
         <latlongregistered>"234"</latlongregistered>
         <totalpoints>876</totalpoints>
         <redeemablepoints>345</redeemablepoints>
         <expirydate>2012-03-14T00:00:00+05:30</expirydate>
         <qrcode>"?"</qrcode>
         <currentoffercount>20</currentoffercount>
         <schemerefid>1</schemerefid>
</insert_subscribe_merchant_operation>
```

Please help me !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the DSS upcoming release (3.5.1). The related JIRA is [DS-1190](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1190). As a workaround you can switch to org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter and org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by modifying wso2 dss axis2.xml

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
              class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>
```

By removing Gson formatters.